# rsync command not preserving permissions

Tags: permissions, rhel, rsync, chown

`rsync` is not preserving permissions/ownesrship after file transfer. Here is the scenario

Source host(`192.168.2.14`  from where files are copied):

Source Path

```
 # ls -l "/shareddata/tesz/"
 total 4
 drwxrwsr-x 2 root admin 4096 Sep 15 19:38 web

 # ls -l /shareddata/tesz/web/
 total 0
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 askar admin 0 Sep 15 19:38 test1 
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 dey   admin 0 Sep 15 19:38 test2
```

Destination Path:

```
 # ls -ld /shareddata/
 drwxrwxr-x. 4 root admin 4096 Sep 15 19:44 /shareddata/
```

The `rsync` command we tried to copy the files is . The script is running under `fsync` user

```
$ id fsync
uid=700(fsync) gid=502(admin) groups=502(admin)


/usr/bin/rsync -rogp 192.168.2.14:/shareddata/tesz /shareddata/
/usr/bin/rsync -av 192.168.2.14:/shareddata/tesz /shareddata/
```

We are running the `rsync` command from the destination host where the files are copied to. But we can see that permissions/ownership not getting preserved after file transfer

```
$ ls -l /shareddata/
  total 8
       drwxrwsr-x 3 fsync admin 4096 Sep 15 19:44 tesz

 $ ls -l /shareddata/tesz/
 total 4
 drwxrwsr-x 2 fsync admin 4096 Sep 15 20:29 web

 $ ls -l /shareddata/tesz/web/
   total 0
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 fsync admin 0 Sep 15 20:29 test1
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 fsync admin 0 Sep 15 20:29 test2
```

What are the modifications I need in `rsync` command so that permissions are preserved.

Comment: You must be root to preserve ownership.

Comment: We will not be able to do use root . Can we use sudo for fsync user to preserve ownership ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the remote rsync process needs to be run with superuser privileges to be able to preserve permissions. If you have sudo access on the remote server you can use the `--rsync-path` option to run rsync as root:

```
rsync -av --rsync-path "sudo rsync" source/ server:/destination/
```

Comment: Is it a issue if I run it as , rsync -av --rsync-path "sudo rsync"   server:/src  /dst  from the  destination server

Comment: In this case you should run `sudo rsync ...` to preserve permissions. You don't need `--rsync-path` as long as you can access all the source files/directories on the source server as the user you're connecting as. Hope that makes sense?